# IEI Notes Direct Transfer Activity

Tags: db2, lotus-notes, db2-luw

I am using a Notes connector with my direct transfer activity to send data to a DB2 LUW table.  The data in the Notes database is text and decimal(7,2) in the external datasource.  I have added this, [image], to the Notes connector and tried several variations of it and each time I get this same error, [image],.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My other option is to transfer the data to a new database, run an agent to convert the data using the formulas included, and then do the direct transfer activity using the new database.

Comment: The error message refers to a field called SETTLEMENT_Amount. The code you are showing does not reference that field at all. Without seeing that, there is no way for anyone to guess what your problem is apart from telling you the same thing that the error message is already telling you: You've got a text value in that field and the connector expects a numeric value.

Comment: Well, it actually seems the issue is that the Direct Transfer Activity is expecting the data type to match in the Notes database, currently Text, with the DB2 table, currently Decimal(7,2), and converting the data using a formula doesn't make a difference.  My new solution to attempt is to transfer the data to a separate database that I have the activity delete and create each time, run an agent in that new database to set new fields of the proper type with the needed data converted, and finally transfer the new fields, with proper format, to the DB2 table.  Shall see how this goes.

Comment: My new solution works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer the data to a separate database which the activity deletes and creates each time based off existing template, run an agent in that new database to set new fields of the proper type with the needed data converted, and finally transfer the new fields, with proper format, to the DB2 table.  Tested and worked.

Although this solution does work our organization has a policy of not creating any new databases so I went the route of using DB2 LUW Stored Procedures to delete my documents and insert the new records with both being called from IEI (fka LEI) direct transfer activities.